# DateTime.TryParseExact only working in "One Way"

Tags: c#, datetime, date-format

**Scope:**

I have been trying to develop a `super-tolerant` DateTime.Parse routine, so I decided to give most "widely-used" formats a try to better understand the `format masks`.

**Problem:**

I have defined a specific format (String) which I use as `myDate.ToString(format)`, and it works wonders. The problem is, If I get this same String (result of the `.ToString(format)` operation), and feed it back to `DateTime.TryParseExact (...)`  it fails.

**Code / Test:**

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

// Defining Format and Testing it via "DateTime.ToString(format)"
string format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"; 
string dtNow  = DateTime.Now.ToString (format);
Console.WriteLine (dtNow);

// Trying to Parse DateTime on the same Format defined Above
DateTime time;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact (dtNow, format, provider,    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out time))
{
    // If TryParseExact Worked
    Console.WriteLine ("Result: " + time.ToString ());  
}
else
{
    // If TryParseExact Failed
    Console.WriteLine ("Failed to Parse Date");
}
```

Output is : `"Failed to Parse Date".`

**Question:**

Why can I use the `format` string to format a certain date as text, but I can't use the same `format` to feed the string back to a date object ?

**EDIT:**

I have added part of my method to [this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M4I8Li), and I would like to know why the "ParseDate" method fails to return a proper date, given that the "String" is in the right format.

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: Try `string dtNow  = DateTime.Now.ToString (format, provider);` Add the culture when converting to string.

Comment: Confirmed it fails with `pt-BR` (Portuguese (Brazil)).

Comment: `pt-BR` is my current culture, but it also fails with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins: [Here is an example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xhCANx) with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` showing it does not fail.

Comment: @JesseGood - your code works if I uncomment the "pt-BR" line too! (Well, after I rename that variable to "provider".)

Comment: @AdamV That's weird, isn't it ?

Comment: @AdamV: Yes, so the lesson should be used the same culture consistently. The reason it works if you use `pt-BR` consistently is because `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` expects a `AM/PM` designator in the string with that format while `pt-BR` does not.

Comment: @JesseGood I have updated my question with another example. What I do not understand is, Why it doesn't work when parsing from a "String". There's no date here, no nothing, just a "String" in the proper format especified by the "TryParseExact" method.

Answer (score 5):

Since you use [`DateTime.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method without any [`IFormatProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx), this method will use your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) settings.

That's why your

```
string dtNow  = DateTime.Now.ToString (format);
```

line *might* generate a different string representation than `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt` format.

Three things can cause this issue;

- Your `CurrentCulture` has a different [`DateSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) than `/`
- Your `CurrentCulture` has a different [`TimeSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) than `:`
- Your `CurrentCulture` has a different or empty string as a [`AMDesignator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.amdesignator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and/or [`PMDesignator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.pmdesignator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Since you try to parse your string with `provider` (which is `InvariantCulture`) on your `DateTime.TryParseExact` method, generate your string based on that provider as well.

```
string dtNow  = DateTime.Now.ToString(format, provider);
```

You told your `CurrentCulture` is `pt-BR` and this culture has empty string `""` as a `AMDesignator` and `PMDesignator`. That's why your `dtNow` string will not have any AM or PM designator on it's representation part.

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/fTnkkM)</kbd>.

Comment: Shouldn't the first line of my code, fix this ? (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins If you use it in your `DateTime.Now.ToString()` method as a second parameter, yes, it will be fix it.

Comment: I have updated my question with another example. What I do not understand is, Why it doesn't work when parsing from a "String". There's no date here, no nothing, just a "String" in the proper format especified by the "TryParseExact" method.

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins What is the point of `System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal |  System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal | System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite | System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowTrailingWhite` exactly? o.O Are you really sure you read what is `DateTimeStyles` exactly for?

Comment: The idea here was to make it as tolerant as possible. I will give those flags a double-check to see if i'm actually messing things up